# How to efficiently make class-to-cluster matching in order to calculate resulting accuracy

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-analysis, confusion-matrix

I am trying to make a match of classes (golden data) with clustering predictions. At the end of my process I have something like:

```
              0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
Class1        0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
Class2        0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
Class3        6  0 10  0  0  0  0  0  4  0
Class4        0  4  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0
Class5        4  0  0  5  0  0  2  0  0  2
Class6        0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0
Class7        2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
Class8        0  0  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0
Class9        0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0
Class10       0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
```

And I need basically to maximize the main diagonal sum switching columns, turning it in something like

```
              6  5   2  1  3  7  0  4  9  8
Class1        1  0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
Class2        0  0   2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
Class3        0  0  10  0  0  0  6  0  0  4
Class4        0  2   0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0
Class5        2  0   0  0  5  0  4  0  2  0
Class6        0  0   0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0
Class7        0  0   0  0  0  0  2  0  0  1
Class8        0  0   0  0  0  0  0  3  0  0
Class9        0  0   0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0
Class10       0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

What I am doing currently is (runnable example) (python/pandas/numpy):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import permutations
from functools import partial
from operator import itemgetter

def diag_sum(cm, columns):
    return np.trace(cm[:,list(columns)])

def confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred):
    classes = list(set(y_true))
    clusters = list(set(y_pred))
    cm = {cla: [0]*len(clusters) for cla in classes}

    for y_t, y_p in zip(y_true, y_pred):
        cm[y_t][y_p] += 1

    cm = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cm, orient='index')

    matrix_cm = cm.as_matrix()
    column_perm = list(permutations(range(matrix_cm.shape[1])))

    result = map(partial(diag_sum, matrix_cm), column_perm)

    index, value = max(enumerate(result), key=itemgetter(1))

    cm = cm[list(column_perm[index])]
    return cm

# Same example as the matrixes above
y_true = ['Class1']*1 + ['Class2']*2 + ['Class3']*20 + ['Class4']*6 + ['Class5']*13 + ['Class6']*2 + ['Class7']*3 + ['Class8']*3 + ['Class9']*2 + ['Class10']*1
y_pred = [6]*1 + [2]*2 + [0]*6 + [2]*10 + [8]*4 + [1]*4 + [5]*2 + [0]*4 + [3]*5 + [6]*2 + [9]*2 + [7]*2 + [0]*2 + [8]*1 + [4]*3 + [3]*2 + [8]*1

print(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred))
```

At the end of the day, it works, but the permutation is really expensive O(n!). I need to execute it thousands of times in a row. Any advice?

I need this because I am working on a problem where classes are different for each new dataset, but I still have the golden for a few datasets were I am running my tests and would really appreciate being able to make if fast.

Comment: Please post a minimum verifiable example, so we an copy-paste it and test possible answers!

Comment: @Joooeey done it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approachh using `scipy.optimize.linprog`.

Explanation: First note that if you write the solutiion as permutation matrix then the objective function is linear. If we can express the constraint that solutions must be permutations in terms of linear equations and inequalities we can hand over to a standard solver. As a matter of fact we can't but we can do the next best thing and allow the convex hull of all permutation matrices. Because the problem is linear this cannot introduce a better solution, so we are essentially done.

Note if the solution is unique this should just find it. If there are multiple solutions it might in theory mix them (in a convex combination; in practice, it doesn't seem to but I'm not expert enough to completely rule it out). If you are only interested in the diagonal sum you can ignore this.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog

def best_perm(A):
    n, n = A.shape
    res = linprog(-A.ravel(),
                  A_eq=np.r_[np.kron(np.identity(n), np.ones((1, n))),
                             np.kron(np.ones((1, n)), np.identity(n))],
                  b_eq=np.ones((2*n,)), bounds=n*n*[(0, None)])
    assert res.success
    return res.x.reshape(n, n).T

import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""              0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
Class1        0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
Class2        0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
Class3        6  0 10  0  0  0  0  0  4  0
Class4        0  4  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0
Class5        4  0  0  5  0  0  2  0  0  2
Class6        0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0
Class7        2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
Class8        0  0  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0
Class9        0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0
Class10       0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0"""), index_col=0, delimiter='\s+')

shuffle = best_perm(df.values)

print(shuffle)

print(df.values @ shuffle)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
[[  1.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   2.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.  10.   0.   0.   0.   6.   0.   0.   4.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   4.   0.   0.   0.   0.   2.   0.]
 [  2.   2.   0.   0.   5.   0.   4.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   2.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   2.   0.   0.   1.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   3.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   2.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.]]
```

Comment: It will take a few months to understand what you have done there, but fits nicely to my task and code. Thanks!

Comment: @LucasPugensFernandes I've added a bit of explanation.

Comment: Yes, I suspected as much, but it is only really important that it works for the majority of cases. Could it generate a matrix with a total sum different of the input matrix sum? What could be expected of this "convex combination" case?

Comment: @LucasPugensFernandes No, the sum will be the same for all legal solutions and all convex combinations.

Comment: No problems, then. :)

Comment: I made a merge with the sklearn library with your code at [link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/10604), if you have a GitHub account, let me know, so I can properly cite you.

Comment: @LucasPugensFernandes Thanks! my github is [here](https://github.com/paul-the-noob).

Answer (score 1):

The [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) is widely known for *exactly* this assignment problem. It will find the **optimum** in O(n³).

However, for evaluating clusterings, better measures exist. Use ARI and NMI. They only need O(n²) and are widely accepted.